# Populating a Wrappannel Dynamically in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-toolkit

this is regarding a best practice advice regarding using MVVM.

I am in need to populate a wrappanel as and when elements are dropped in to it. The elements are not uniform, they can be either labels or text boxes. Depending on a value of a parameter the element added varies.

I did this in code behind. Now I am in the process of moving the entire thing to an MVVM model am stuck with the way to do this without affecting the MVVM core principals. In this code I have both UI elements and logic content to gether which are tightly related; and I have become incapable to seperate the two to suite MVVM.

I tried creating the UI elements in the VM, populating a ObservableCollection of type UIElement and binding it to the itemssource property (Subsequently I changed wrappanel to be a listview to be effective in the whole thing). But this did not work out since when I bind the elements there is no way the code can understand which UIelement.

Posted below is the section of the code which I need to seperate:

```
private void CreateVisulaQueryContent() {

            VisualQueryObject visualQueryData = new VisualQueryObject();

            VisualQueryObject helperVisualQueryObject = DraggedData as    VisualQueryObject;


            //***Taking a copy of the static DraggedData object to be bound

                visualQueryData.ColumnDiscriptor = helperVisualQueryObject.ColumnDiscriptor;

            visualQueryData.ComparedValue = helperVisualQueryObject.ComparedValue;

            visualQueryData.JoinWithColumnDescriptor = helperVisualQueryObject.JoinWithColumnDescriptor;

            visualQueryData.LabelType = helperVisualQueryObject.LabelType;
            visualQueryData.OperatorValue = helperVisualQueryObject.OperatorValue;


            if (visualQueryData.LabelType == "column")
            {

                ColumnDescriptionObject descriptionValue = visualQueryData.ColumnDiscriptor;
                Label droppedElement = new Label();

                Binding binding = new Binding();
                binding.Source = visualQueryData;
                binding.Path = new PropertyPath("ColumnDiscriptor");
                binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                droppedElement.SetBinding(Label.DataContextProperty, binding);

                droppedElement.Content = visualQueryData.ColumnDiscriptor.TableName + "." + visualQueryData.ColumnDiscriptor.ColumnName;


                droppedElement.Foreground = Brushes.White;
                droppedElement.Background = Brushes.DarkOrange;

                droppedElement.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5);

                droppedLabel.MouseDoubleClick += columnLabel_MouseDown;
                ViewUIElements.Add(droppedElement);

            }
            else if (visualQueryData.LabelType == "controller")
            {

                Label droppedElement = new Label();

                Binding binding = new Binding();
                binding.Source = visualQueryData;
                binding.Path = new PropertyPath("OperatorValue");
                binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                droppedElement.SetBinding(Label.DataContextProperty, binding);


                droppedElement.Content = draggedContent.OperatorValue;
                droppedElement.Foreground = Brushes.White;
                droppedElement.Background = Brushes.Crimson;
                droppedElement.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5);

                droppedElement.MouseDoubleClick += columnLabel_MouseDown;

                ViewUIElements.Add(new Label());

            }
            else if (visualQueryData.LabelType == "value")
            {
                TextBox droppedElement = new TextBox();

                Binding binding = new Binding();
                binding.Source = visualQueryData;
                binding.Path = new PropertyPath("ComparedValue");
                binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                droppedElement.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);

               droppedElement.MouseDoubleClick += columnLabel_MouseDown;

                ViewUIElements.Add(droppedElement);
            }

            QueryDesignerModel.QueryDesignHelperCollection.Add(visualQueryData);

    }
```

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: What is the question exactly?  I know how to display items dynamically (ItemsSource with ItemPanelTemplate) and how to get rid of UIElements in ViewModels (use datatemplateselector). But what should I write in my answer?

Comment: Hi vorrtex, thanks for the comment. This is about adding dynamic content to a Wrappanel (or a listview) in a wpf application the MVVM way. Also before adding the content to the panel I need to check the user request and upon that the added element can be either a lable or a textbox. This is the problem in a nut shell. Do let me know if my problem is still vague.

Comment: Ok, I write an example after some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I promised, I have created an example in which there is no `UIElements` inside `ViewModels`.

First of all, I removed lot of code from your method:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //For demonstration
        this.ViewUIElements = new ObservableCollection<VisualQueryObject>
        {
            new VisualQueryObject{LabelType = "column", ColumnDiscriptor = new DescriptionModel("Table1", "Column2") },
            new VisualQueryObject{LabelType = "controller"},
            new VisualQueryObject{LabelType = "value"},
        };
    }

    public void UpdateCollection(VisualQueryObject helperVisualQueryObject)
    {
        VisualQueryObject visualQueryData = new VisualQueryObject();
        //I would remove copying, but maybe it is intended behavior
        //***Taking a copy of the static DraggedData object to be bound           
        visualQueryData.ColumnDiscriptor = helperVisualQueryObject.ColumnDiscriptor;
        visualQueryData.ComparedValue = helperVisualQueryObject.ComparedValue;
        visualQueryData.JoinWithColumnDescriptor = helperVisualQueryObject.JoinWithColumnDescriptor;
        visualQueryData.LabelType = helperVisualQueryObject.LabelType;
        visualQueryData.OperatorValue = helperVisualQueryObject.OperatorValue;

        this.ViewUIElements.Add(visualQueryData);

        //QueryDesignerModel.QueryDesignHelperCollection.Add(visualQueryData);   //I don't know what this method does
    }

    public ObservableCollection<VisualQueryObject> ViewUIElements { get; private set; }
}
```

Then I created the `DataTemplateSelector` class where I've put if-clauses from the function in your question:

```
public class QueryObjectDateTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ColumnTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate ControllerTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate ValueTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
        var visualQueryData = item as VisualQueryObject;
        if (visualQueryData == null)
            return null;

        if (visualQueryData.LabelType == "column")
            return ColumnTemplate;
        else if (visualQueryData.LabelType == "controller")
            return ControllerTemplate;
        else if (visualQueryData.LabelType == "value")
            return ValueTemplate;
        else return null;

    }
}
```

And that's almost all. Everything else is in `xaml`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="WrapPanelTemplate">
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ColumnDataTemplate">
        <Label DataContext="{Binding ColumnDiscriptor}" Foreground="White" Background="DarkOrange" BorderThickness="5">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding TableName}"/><Run Text="."/><Run Text="{Binding ColumnName}"/> 
            </TextBlock>
        </Label>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ControllerDataTemplate">
        <Label Content="Controller"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ValueDataTemplate">
        <TextBox Text="Value"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:QueryObjectDateTemplateSelector x:Key="ModelSelector"
                                           ColumnTemplate="{StaticResource ColumnDataTemplate}"
                                           ControllerTemplate="{StaticResource ControllerDataTemplate}"
                                           ValueTemplate="{StaticResource ValueDataTemplate}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewUIElements}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource WrapPanelTemplate}" 
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ModelSelector}"/>
</Grid>
```

I have coded only the Column Template, other templates should be rewritten in xaml too.
So now you can call this method:

```
((MainViewModel)this.DataContext).UpdateCollection(DraggedData as VisualQueryObject);
```

Comment: Hi Vorrtex, I really really appreciate the effort you have taken to do this code. It is great. I learnt a massive amount of datatemplating from the code you've given. Now I am going to try it. I will comment here about the progress soon. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are after, but it sounds like you want to use data templating to change the `ItemTemplate` for a `ListBox` based on the underlying bound data object type.

So, in your case you can have an `ObservableCollection<LabelType>` where label type has derived types for each of your label types (column, controller, value), then use implicit data templates (using the `DataType` property) to select an appropriate template for each sub type.

Alternatively, you could have one `LabelType` with an enumeration for the type of object.

```
ObservableCollection<LabelType> Labels ...

Labels.Add(new ControllerLabelType());

...

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Labels}">
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ControllerLabelType}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding OperatorValue}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ValueLabelType}">
      <TextBox Text="{Binding OperatorValue}" />
    </DataTemplate>        
  </ListBox.Resources>
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx for more on data templating.

Comment: Hi devdigital, thanks for your detailed answer. I will try it and comment on the progress